# Mostrar mi gráfico al darle clic a mi sistema y botón

Tags: javascript

Tengo mi **date range picker**, **select2** y un **boton**, el cuál, en mi select2 se me filtran unos sistemas (son 7), y mediante ese sistema se me genera una gráfica(de acuerdo a cada sistema); ahora bien; al seleccionar mi sistema y darle clic a mi botón **Buscar** (sin seleccionar una fecha me debe de mandar la fecha de hoy por default!) no me muestra mi gráfica, más sin en cambio, cuando selecciono mi sistema y selecciono mi fecha de mi **date range picker** si me manda mis datos (gráfica y se me rellena mi tabla).
¿alguien puede ayudarme?

Código donde esta mi ajax:

```
  function init_daterangepicker(){

...

  $('#div_daterange').daterangepicker(optionSet, cb);
  $('#div_daterange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
    if($("#select2_sistema").is(':enabled')) // estar en tercera persona (estado del select (hablitado o inabilitado (esta habilitado)))
    {
    if($("#select2_sistema").val() == 0)
    {
        //mensaje, 
        $("#idSystem").after(`<label class="label label-warning msg_username" style="float:right;"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>Campo Faltante</label>`);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(".msg_username").fadeOut(1500).remove();
        }, 2000);
        // alert("falta campo");
    }else
      {
        // alert("Campo lleno");
      }
    }

    var startDate = picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    var endDate = picker.endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    var sistemDI =  $('#select2_sistema').val();
    if(sistemDI != null ){
      $.ajax({ 
      type: "POST",
      url: '/client/mes/production/production/fridgeProductivity/',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
          'operationNo':1,
          'sistemDI' : $('#select2_sistema').select2('val'),
          'startDate':startDate,
          'endDate': endDate,   
          'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}',
      },
      success: function(cntxAjax) {
        $('#SearchBut').prop('enable', true);
        set_graphs(cntxAjax.cntxPQ, cntxAjax.cntxRQ);
        table.clear().draw()
        var sumaCumu = 0;
        cntxAjax.cntxDato.forEach(function(datos){
          var valPQ = parseInt(datos[0])
          var valRQ = parseInt(datos[1])
          var cumu = valPQ - valRQ  
          sumaCumu += cumu
          console.log(sumaCumu)
          table.row.add({
            '0': datos[0],
            '1': datos[1],
            '2': cumu,
            '3': sumaCumu,
            '4': datos[2],
          }).draw();            
        })


      }
      });
    }
    startDateA = startDate + ' '+ (moment(startDate).add(00, 'hours').add(00, 'minutes').format('HH:mm'));
    endDateA = endDate + ' '+ (moment(endDate).add(23, 'hours').add(59, 'minutes').format('HH:mm'));
    dataFilter(sistemDI,endDateA,endDateA);
    if (startDate == endDate){
        endDate = moment(picker.endDate).add(1, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    }
        });         
    }
```

Código de mi botón buscar

```
$('#SearchBut').on('click', function(){


 var sistemDI = $('#select2_sistema').val();
  $("#graficaNevera").css('display', 'inline-block');
  if($("#select2_sistema").is(':enabled')) 
    {
        if($("#select2_sistema").val() == 0)
        {
            //mensaje, 
            $("#idSystem").after(`<label class="label label-warning msg_username" style="float:right;"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>Campo Faltante</label>`);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(".msg_username").fadeOut(1500).remove();
            }, 2000);
            // alert("falta campo");
        }else
        {
            // alert("Campo lleno");
        }
    }
  alert(sistemDI);
  dataFilter(sistemDI);
});
```

¡Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacer algo como esto:

```
now = new Date();
let d = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
let m = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
let y = now.getFullYear();
// valida que no este vacio, en caso contrario asigna el valor por defecto
var sistemDI = $('#select2_sistema').val() != ""? $('#select2_sistema').val() : "defaultcategoria";
// valida que no este vacio, en caso contrario asigna el valor por defecto
let startDate = picker.startDate != ""? picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD') : `${y}-${m}-${d-1}`;
// valida que no este vacio, en caso contrario asigna el valor por defecto
let endDate = picker.endDate != ""? picker.endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD') : `${y}-${m}-${d}`;


console.log(`default start: ${y}-${m}-${d-1}`);
console.log(`default end: ${y}-${m}-${d}`);
```

Comment: Me marca este error en consola  Uncaught ReferenceError: picker is not defined

Comment: es una referencia! ya que no se de donde sacar la varible picker pense que era el valor de `input date` lo que me refiero es que puedes validar que si esta `vacia` asigne algo por defecto~